# How to assign a variable that contains a * in the korn shell when read from a text file

Tags: shell, scripting

I am trying to write a housekeeping script that uses a 'driver file' (text file) The entries will be similar to the is :-

```
$INST_YOP/logs/ora/10.1.3/Apache/*.log
```

This is a cut down version of the script but illustrates what I need to do :-

```
while read DATA
do
  eval DATA=$DATA
  echo "Data => "$DATA
  DIR=$(dirname $DATA)
  echo "Dir =>" $DIR
TMP_FILE_NAME="${DATA##*/}"
#TMP_FILE_NAME=$(echo $DATA| awk -F "/" '{ print $NF}')
  echo " ***** TMP_FILE_NAME  => " $TMP_FILE_NAME
  if [[ -d $DIR ]]
  then
    cd $DIR
  fi
  cd $DIR

done < $HOME/scripts/APP_archive_list.DONOTREMOVE
```

I basically want to assign the variable TMP_FILE_NAME=*.log, I don't want the shell to expand it.

I have tried escaping the * in the text file :-

```
$INST_YOP/logs/ora/10.1.3/Apache/\*.log
```

But it still expands, I have tried awk (above) and basename and the method above but they all expand
any ideas on how I can achieve what I need to do please ?

Comment: Do you really need that first `eval`? That seems like a problem right at the top. In all cases, quote any varName references so they are like `"$DATA"`. Use the shell debug/trace feature `set -vx` to see what code is being executed and how it has been evaluated (with variable values expanded). YOu'll see a leading `+` char for those lines. Good luck!

Comment: Separate issue, but you seem to have logic at the end that is essentially "if the directory `$DIR` exists, then `cd` there; then, `cd` there anyway"...

Comment: I'm tempted to -1 this because, well, there isn't a problem with the assignment at all, making the question highly misleading. The problems are with usage (and `eval`).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not that `*` is expanded when you assign to the variable; it's expanded when you *expand* the variable. Always quote parameter expansions, unless you know when not to.

```
while read DATA
do
  echo "Data => $DATA"
  DIR=$(dirname "$DATA")
  echo "Dir => $DIR"
  TMP_FILE_NAME="${DATA##*/}"
  echo " ***** TMP_FILE_NAME  => $TMP_FILE_NAME"
  if [[ -d $DIR ]]
  then
    cd "$DIR"
  fi    
done < "$HOME"/scripts/APP_archive_list.DONOTREMOVE
```